# How to use * in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sqlserver

I have table in database which stores few queries, Using sqlcmd I am trying to retrieve the queries.
While doing so, the select * from abc is getting replaced with 'select  from abc'

How to overcome this issue?

**Edit:**

```
Max_Values=5
n=1
while [ $n -le $Max_Values ]
do
Sql_Qry="set nocount on;Select Query from dbo.abc With(nolock) Where RowID=$n"  

Query=`/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S Server_name -U UserID -P Password -d database -Q "$Sql_Qry" -h -1`
echo $Query
n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Select * from Int.Table1
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Select Script1.txt script2.sh script3.sh from Int.Table1
```

The script1, script2 and script3 are files within the current directory

Comment: Correct quoting is the answer. Please edit your question to show us the whole command you're trying to run.

Comment: @Panki Please refer the the Edit

Comment: `echo "$Query"`, maybe? Always quote your variables.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks, that fixed it

Comment: You haven't got `*` in your query. Does your question title actually reflect the question being asked?

Comment: The queries in column 'Query' from table dbo.abc contains *, please check the expected and actual Output for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Double quote the variable that you want to print will fix the problem.
i.e.

`echo "$Query"`